# How to get part of href link using Selenium in java?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, webdriver

I need to compare current url (in chrome) to a specific href link.
the specific href link **contains two urls**! 
 [i need to get the first link (there are two links in href)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPq9I.png)

```
<a href="http://pubcontentqa.perion.com/dz2/html/interstitial.html?http://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment_and_arts" target="_blank">
```

the implementation should be in **java** using **Selenium**...

thanks!!!

Comment: Good luck. Let us know how it turned out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get attribute to get href from web page. for example

```
String string=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//path of your element")).getAttribute("href");
```

As said, this string contains two url, so can split those

```
String string = "004-034556";
String[] parts = string.split("?"); // as per condition, split here
String url1 = parts[0]; //URL one
String url2 = parts[1]; // URL two
```

Now you have url1 and url2 and do what you want.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: @Keren Please make this answer right. So everyone get this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't contain 2 URLs, it contains 1 URL.

The part after the ? is the URL parameters ([See Understanding URLs on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Understanding_URLs)).  Yours is slightly strange because they are normally key/value pairs, however it is still valid.

The correct way to get the URL parameters is to parse the URL like so:

```
    String hrefAttribute = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("YOUR_LOCATOR")).getAttribute("href");
    URL hrefAsURL = new URL(hrefAttribute);
    String urlParameters = hrefAsURL.getQuery();
```

You could then perform additional actions on the urlParameters if you have a series of key/value pairs (which is what you would normally see), e.g. put them in a Map for use somewhere else:

```
    Map<String, String> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] keyValuePairs = urlParameters.split("&");
    for (String joinedPair : keyValuePairs) {
        String[] separatedPair = joinedPair.split("=");
        parameterMap.put(URLDecoder.decode(separatedPair[0], "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(separatedPair[1], "UTF-8"));
    }
```